# How can I reuse a field in several bridges in Hibernate Search 6?

Tags: hibernate-search, hibernate-search-6

In Hibernate Search 5 I had several custom bridges that populated the same field. That was handy so that I can perform a query on just one field. Now if I try to do it I receive this error:

```
HSEARCH600034: Duplicate index field definition: 'attributes'. Index field names must be unique. Look for two property mappings with the same field name, or two indexed-embeddeds with prefixes that lead to conflicting index field names, or two custom bridges declaring index fields with the same name.
```

I have not found a way to get an existing field from the PropertyBinding Context when implementing the PropertyBinder, only the documented way to add new fields:

```
    IndexFieldReference<String> attributesField = schemaElement
            .field("attributes", f -> f.asString())
            .toReference();
```

Am I missing something or is no longer possible and I need to add new fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I reuse a field in several bridges in Hibernate Search 6?

At the moment, you cannot.

This limitation is a side effect from the (many) sanity checks that Hibernate Search 6 performs on startup, which prevent common mistakes and indirectly  allow a more intuitive behavior in the Search DSL.

Your options are pretty much this:

- Either you refactor your bridges to regroup all code that contributes to the same field in a single bridge (either a `TypeBridge`, or a `PropertyBridge` applied to a [non-persisted getter](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-reindexing-derivedfrom) that returns an aggregated list of all values you're interested in).
- Or you change your bridges to each contribute to its own field, and change your search code to target all these fields at once; most (if not all) predicates [allow targeting multiple fields in the same predicate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-predicate-common-multiple-fields).

The second solution is also the recommended way of indexing, since it produces more accurate relevance scores.

EDIT: If you go for solution 2, this (not yet implemented) feature might be of interest to you: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3926